# Is there a simplified expression for $\prod_{i=1}^N (\sum_{j=1}^i a_j)$?

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials

Can the product of terms $\prod_{i=1}^N (\sum_{j=1}^i a_j)$, be expanded and simplified in a general form for the polynomial.

This product is of the form $$
a_1\cdot(a_1+a_2)\cdot(a_1+a_2+a_3)\cdot ...\cdot(a_1+...+a_n)
$$

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is $a_n$ ? If they are in AP, there is a result

Comment: $a_n$ are succesive integrals of the form $\int_{n-1}^nf$

Comment: Yes, you can think of this product as
$$\sum _{\substack{(b_1,b_2,\cdots ,b_n)\\ 1\leq b_i\leq i}}\prod _{1\leq i\leq n} a_{b_i}.$$
It turns out that the sequence of $n-$tuples is in bijection with permutations of $n$ elements via inversion sets.